# Suppose $X\perp Y \mid Z_1$ for r.v.'s $X,Y,Z_1$. What general conditions must exist for a new r.v. $Z_2$ such that $X\perp Y \mid Z_1, Z_2$?

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose $X\perp Y \mid Z_1$ for random variables $X,Y,Z_1$. That is, $X$ and $Y$ are independent conditional on $Z_1$. Suppose we now have a new random variable $Z_2$. I am wondering if there exists general conditions so that $X\perp Y \mid Z_1, Z_2$?

Ideally, I would like to use the fact $X\perp Y \mid Z_1$ but am having a hard time deriving explicit conditions by factoring and so forth. Do such conditions exist? I would appreciate any insight or helpful pointers, thank you.

Comment: One condition that works is $Z_2 = f(Z_1)$ for some (deterministic) function $f$.  One condition that doesn't work is $Z_2 \perp Z_1$.

Comment: Thank you, I am wondering why the function needs to be deterministic. Is there an example of what might happen if it is stochastic? Would you have any suggestions or frameworks/methodologies for how I might be able to derive general conditions?

Comment: I don't know what would be the "most general" conditions, but saying $X \perp Y | Z$ does not really say much at all.  For all you know $Z$ is something completely unrelated to everything else.  Then you're just saying $X \perp Y$.  Now if you condition on $Z_2$ also, you're basically asking under what condition you have $X \perp Y | Z_2$...  At least when $Z_2 = f(Z_1)$, you know you are not "adding any information"

Comment: Thanks, how can I go about explicitly proving the condition of $Z_2 = f(Z_1)$? Would it be possible by regular probability manipulations?

Comment: IMHO this depends what you mean by "regular" :) e.g. do you accept that $P(Z_1 = a, Z_2 = f(a)) = P(Z_1 = a) \forall a$?  This isn't one of the "regulars" but it is "obvious" and, if desired, can be fully justified by equating the events (subsets of sample space).

Comment: Thanks, to understand your formula, is it formally read, if $Z_2$ is defined by the functional transformation where $P(Z_1 = a, Z_2 = f(a)) = P(Z_1 = a) \forall a$, then the above conditions hold?

Comment: Sure...  that equation is equiv to $P(Z_2 = f(a) | Z_1 = a) = 1$ BTW

Comment: I tried proving it would not hold under $Z_2\perp Z_1$, but it doesn't seem to work out for me. Could I ask how you envisioned this condition holding? I have that $P(X \mid Y,Z_1,Z_2) = \dfrac{P(X,Y,Z_1,Z_2)}{P(Y,Z_1,Z_2)} = \dfrac{P(X,Y\mid Z_1,Z_2)}{P(Y\mid Z_1,Z_2)}$. At this point, I am not sure how the fact of $Z_1\perp Z_2$ will cause it not to hold or one way or the other. Could you tell me what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: When I said "One condition that doesn't work is $Z_2 \perp Z_1$" I never meant it will _never_ work.  I simply meant you cannot conclude $X \perp Y \mid Z_1, Z_2$, i.e., there will be counter-examples.  See my Answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partial Answer / Summarizing & expanding on the comments

**Observation 1:** If $Z_2 = f(Z_1)$ for some (deterministic) function $f$ then $X\perp Y \mid Z_1 \implies X \perp Y \mid Z_1, Z_2$

Proof: If $Z_2 = f(Z_1)$, then we have: (i)  $P(Z_1=a, Z_2 \neq f(a)) = 0$, and, (ii) for any event $B$, $P(B, Z_1=a) = P(B, Z_1=a, Z_2=f(a)).$   Using these:

$$P(B \mid Z_1=a, Z_2=f(a)) = {P(B, Z_1=a, Z_2=f(a)) \over P(Z_1=a, Z_2=f(a))} ={P(B, Z_1=a) \over P(Z_1=a)} = P(B \mid Z_1=a) \ \ \ \ \ \ [*]$$

Therefore:

$$\begin{align}
P(X=x, Y=y \mid Z_1=a, Z_2=f(a)) &= P(X=x, Y=y \mid Z_1=a)\\
&=P(X=x\mid Z_1=a)P(Y=y \mid Z_1=a)\\
&=P(X=x\mid Z_1=a, Z_2=f(a))P(Y=y \mid Z_1=a, Z_2=f(a))
\end{align}
$$

where the first and third equalities come from $[*]$ and the second equality is the given $X \perp Y \mid Z_1$.  But now, the equality between the LHS with the final RHS is exactly $X \perp Y \mid Z_1, Z_2$.

**Observation 2:** $Z_1\perp Z_2$ is insufficient, i.e. $Z_1\perp Z_2$ and $X\perp Y \mid Z_1$ together do not imply $X \perp Y \mid Z_1, Z_2$

Proof: To show "do not imply", all we need is one example where $Z_1 \perp Z_2$ and $X \perp Y \mid Z_1$ but $X \not\perp Y \mid Z_1, Z_2$.  We will satisfy the $Z_1$ requirements by simply making it independent of everything else, after which the requirements reduce to $X \perp Y$ but $X \not\perp Y \mid Z_2.$  This is easy e.g. by using the well-known example of events which are pairwise independent but not mutually independent.

- $X =$ first fair coin flip is Heads
- $Y =$ second fair coin flip is Heads
- $Z_2 =$ the two flips show same result
- $Z_1 =$ something completely unrelated, e.g. third fair coin flip is Heads

**Observation 2b:** Even adding $X\perp Y \mid Z_2$ is still insufficient.  Simply modify the example above with $Z_2 =$ the three flips have an odd number of Heads.

---

Come to think of it, I think the *main* idea here is actually this: any *conditional* distribution is itself a distribution, or a "probability law" as some people might say.  So, conditioned on $Z_1$, you can have any (conditional) distribution $F_{XY}$ you want on $X,Y$ and you want to specify $X \perp Y$, fine.  But conditioned on $Z_1, Z_2$, you can *also* have any (conditional) distribution $G_{XY}$ you want, and there are very, very few restrictions on $G$.  One restriction is if $(X,Y)$ cannot take a value $(x,y)$ under $F$ then they also cannot take that value under $G$, but aside from that (and I may be missing some other corner cases), you have basically free choice of $G$.  I used this "freedom" of choice in Observation 2.

In Observation 1, of course you do not have any choice in $G$, because $G =F$.

Comment: May I ask what the importance of $P(Z_1=a, Z_2 \neq f(a)) = 0$ is in the first proof?